# Crosstab with static column

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports, crosstab

How can I make a static column/row in crosstab? See example below; can I have a fixed jan, feb, march, ... columns instead of it generating dynamically?

```
location       jan   feb   mar   apr   may   jun   jul   aug   sep   oct   nov   dec 
london         500   62    200   50    0     60    100   46    89    200   150   210
paris          50    26    20    500   50    70    40    200   0     40    250   50
```

I want the column (jan, feb, mar, apr, ...)  to always show up regardless of their measures zero or have values. Like they are fixed.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
select sum("AMOUNT"), "REQUESTDATE","description" 
from(
SELECT SUM(e.AMOUNT)"AMOUNT",TO_CHAR(REQUESTDATE,'MM')"REQUESTDATE", CA.DESCR "description"
FROM PC_PAYMENTTRXNLOG PC,GLB_TYPE ca, PC_ESERVICEINQUIRY e
where PC.ESERVICE_ID = E.ID 
AND trunc(REQUESTDATE) between trunc(to_date('2012-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) and trunc(to_date('2012-06-30','yyyy-mm-dd'))
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(REQUESTDATE,'MM'),CA.DESCR 
 )
group by "REQUESTDATE","description"
```

and the output

```
    SUM("amount") Requestdate    Description
    2550405         04           A
    2550405         04           B
    23893281        05           C
    614977          06           A
    614977          06           E
    2550405         04           C
```

now after updated the query to be

```
  select sum("AMOUNT"), month,"description" 
  from(
  SELECT SUM(e.AMOUNT)"AMOUNT",TO_CHAR(REQUESTDATE,'MM')"REQUESTDATE", CA.DESCR "description"
  FROM PC_PAYMENTTRXNLOG PC,GLB_TYPE ca, PC_ESERVICEINQUIRY e
  where PC.ESERVICE_ID = E.ID 
  AND trunc(REQUESTDATE) between trunc(to_date('2012-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) and trunc(to_date('2012-06-30','yyyy-mm-dd'))
  GROUP BY TO_CHAR(REQUESTDATE,'MM'),CA.DESCR 
   ) 
 full outer join (select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
+ numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mm') as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12) on month="REQUESTDATE"
  group by month,"description"
```

when run the query run it displaying all the months regardless of their measures zero or have values.

BUT now the output is like that

```
location       jan   feb   mar   apr   may   jun   jul   aug   sep   oct   nov   dec 
london         500   62    200   50    0     60    100   46    89    200   150   210
paris          50    26    20    500   50    70    40    200   0     40    250   50
null            0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0    0      0     0     0
```

how i can restrict/hide the last null row?

Comment: in the query itself.. use full outer join with months. simple

Comment: can you please explain more.

Comment: how are u getting month? include sample query or attach an sqlfiddle

Comment: my query
`select count("NUMBER OF RECEIPT"), sum("AMOUNT"), "REQUESTDATE","description"
from (SELECT  PC.ID "NUMBER OF RECEIPT", SUM(e.AMOUNT) "AMOUNT", TO_CHAR(REQUEST_TIMESTAMP, 'MM') "REQUESTDATE",CA.DESCR "description"
FROM PC_PAYMENTTRXNLOG PC,GLB_TYPE ca, PC_ESERVICEINQUIRY e,
where PC.ESERVICE_ID = E.ID AND ca.ID=E.CARDTYPE AND trunc(REQUESTDATE) between trunc(to_date('2012-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) and trunc(to_date('2012-06-30','yyyy-mm-dd'))
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(REQUEST_TIMESTAMP, 'MM'), PC.ID,CA.DESCR )
group by "REQUESTDATE","description"`

month display like

requestdate
06
06
05
05
04
04

Comment: edit and add it in your question, and add tags which database you are using. and sample sql output or sqlfiddle. plz be more clear. And always remember to use aliasing then fetching records in select query.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: that description is your Location?

Comment: It is difficult to answer your question without providing sample code of `measure, column - iReport`, Hint: for `location` column use property's `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` and `isBlankWhenNull` to `True` and use Print when expression for the measures so that it'll not print when location is blank.

Comment: what the expression that i can put for this case?
please give an example for the expression

Comment: @Omrak_Taybeh cannot help without knowing field names for more info on print when expression visit this http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543453/ireport-print-when-expression

Comment: i have checked `RemoveLineWhenBlank` and `BlankWhenNull` for location column and the null value disappear but for the measures i tried to put in the expression  `new Boolean($F{location} != null)` but i get an error `Field not found : location`

Comment: cant help further without knowing the names of field and how u created it..

Comment: the fields are amount, month and description.
they created from the query.

Comment: i tried to put `new Boolean($F{description} != null)` in the filter expression of crosstab data but this will prevent the other months with 0 value from appear.
and that's will back me to the point 0

Comment: i have put `new Boolean($F{description} != null)` in every measures in the crosstab also, i have checked `RemoveLineWhenBlank` and `BlankWhenNull` for description and try to run, the report displayed without the null row.

Comment: @Mani Deep I would like to thank you very much for your kind help and support, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have not tested it.. but try something like this

```
select sum("AMOUNT"), month,"description" 
from(SELECT SUM(e.AMOUNT)"AMOUNT",TO_CHAR(REQUESTDATE,'MM')"REQUESTDATE", CA.DESCR "description"
FROM PC_PAYMENTTRXNLOG PC,GLB_TYPE ca, PC_ESERVICEINQUIRY e
where PC.ESERVICE_ID = E.ID 
AND trunc(REQUESTDATE) between trunc(to_date('2012-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')) and trunc(to_date('2012-06-30','yyyy-mm-dd'))
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(REQUESTDATE,'MM'),CA.DESCR 
 ) 
full outer join (select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
+ numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mm') as month
from dual
connect by level <= 12) on month="REQUESTDATE"
group by month,"description"
```

click here for [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/8602) demo to generate 1 to 12 in Oracle

Once you have generated this.. full outer join Your main query with this series query and take month from series query as I did in main query.

Using this query you will get all the data for all months with null values in measure.

For `Description` column - iReport set property's isRemoveLineWhenBlank and isBlankWhenNull to True, This will remove the null value being printed in iReport

For `Measure` use [Print when expression](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543453/ireport-print-when-expression) in such a way, when ever description is null then return false. So this will prevent the value `0` being printed in iReport.

Comment: i tried instead of `select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
    + numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mm') as month
  from dual
  connect by level <= 12` this one `SELECT to_char(to_date( level,'mm'), 'mm') as month FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=12`
but still got the same error.

Comment: @Omorak_Taybeh i have added sql fiddle, as u have tagged oracle db in ur question.

Comment: when i put the query that generate that months with the main query, i get SQL command not properly ended error.

Comment: i have found what causes the error! the name of two tables (a,m), by removing them, the query will run successfully! :) but the result show a new null row! how i can hide this row?

Comment: @Omorak_Taybeh plz edit the answer with minor changes u made. and can u update the question once again? with more clear code?

Comment: i have just updated the query with a minor changes, which are the name of two tables since you provided each select with a name (m,a). so i just remove them.